Optimizing code for detecting adjacent items in an array with SIMD instructions?
I have a function written in C++ that checks if two specific elements are adjacent to each other in an array. The function works fine, but I want to optimize it using SIMD to improve performance. Here is the current implementation of the function:
int check_adjacent_impl(uint8_t *arr, int size, int a, int b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
    {
        if ((arr[i] == a && arr[i + 1] == b) || (arr[i] == b && arr[i + 1] == a))
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

I am still not very familiar with SIMD, so I am still struggling with it. Also, it will be nice if anyone can provide me with any documentation/tutorial/etc. Thanks in advance!

Any particular SIMD ISA, like x86 with SSE2 or AVX2 vs. AArch64 with NEON/ASIMD or SVE?  Regardless, you'd normally want to load vectors from the array, so the tricky part is when a match spans the boundary between two SIMD vectors.  Depending on the ISA and whether your input arr is normally aligned, scalar checks of the boundary elements (perhaps with an unaligned 16-bit load) could be ok, otherwise vector shuffling, partially-overlapping unaligned loads, or other tricks might be best.

If you are looking for a better use of your processor, couldn't you save some instructions by skipping every other cell in the array? E.g. if arr[1] is neither a nor b, is there a point to look at arr[0]? And if it is not equal to them, then checking arr[2] can be skipped too if arr[3] is neither a nor b. Then keep going. On another note, your array is uint8_t* while a and b are int, your compiler should be telling you about the inconsistency of size/sign (and you should address it).

You could simply look for either a or b — assume you choose a.  When you find an a, look at the two adjacent cells (if they exist) to see whether either is b.  Whether that translates into SIMD code or not is another matter, but it has the possibility of being more efficient.

@Atmo: Better to check 2 bytes at a time so you have fewer false positives, each of which probably result in a branch mispredict unless there's a pattern to the distribution of as or bs.  Plus, checking 16 bytes at a time is obviously better than 1 or 2.

@Jonathan: same argument applies to SIMD.  Breaking out of a loop every time you find an a candidate is unlikely to be the optimal strategy.  Although it is quite simple to implement, just copy the code for a SIMD memchr, or port from asm to C with intrinsics.  On a SIMD ISA where you can get a bitmap of match positions within a vector (e.g. x86 with _mm_movemask_epi8), you can loop over them with msk &= msk-1; (x86 BLSR does that in one instruction instead of 2) between each std::countr_zero (tzcnt)

Different SIMD ISAs have big differences in how you go about branching on a SIMD compare for things like memchr or this.  x86 has pmovmskb; AArch64 has a narrowing shift-and-insert or something, I forget the details.  And 32-bit NEON on older ARMv7 CPUs is often inefficient as SIMD->GPR data movement stalls the pipeline because they're not tightly coupled enough for out-of-order exec of an integer instruction that depends on a SIMD result (unlike x86 and unlike most ARMv8 CPUs.)  But AArch64 SVE has compare-into-mask. So that part of the details depends a lot on what SIMD ISA.

Are you interested in alternative ways to code this without SIMD?

This feels like an XY problem... How often do the parameter values change, and how big is the array of bytes being scanned? Performing many searches for varying pairs of bytes on an array that does not change often could be done very efficiently by preprocessing the array contents into an 8K buffer of bit flags, then using simple indexing to check a bit value. "The function works fine" is a pre-emptive restriction on this question (as the OP's presented code is sub-optimal).

While compilers can sometimes auto-vectorize C++ code, all mainstream compilers fail to do that on this simple function.
There are several approach to vectorize a C++ code.

C SIMD intrinsics
The most famous is C SIMD intrinsics which are great for performance but not portable and makes your code really ugly and also harder to maintain/debug. On x86-64 CPUs, you can write a code targetting SSE4.2 which is supported on nearly-all modern CPUs, but it will not be very efficient. A lot of x86-64 CPUs supports AVX2 so you can write a code for that which will be pretty efficient, but it will simply crash on rather-old CPUs not supporting it (~6% based on the Steam survey). For very good performance on large arrays, AVX-512 is the way to go, but it is supported only on a fraction of client-side CPUs (12% based on the Steam survey). Most recent server-side CPUs support it though. On ARM, Neon is generally the way to go though some recent CPUs support SVE. This SIMD instruction set fragmentation is a pain when writing C/C++ code using C SIMD intrinsics. Thus, I do not advise you to use C SIMD intrinsics unless you target only one specific platform.

C++ SIMD libraries
A frequent alternative solution is to use a C++ library for that since the experimental SIMD technical specification is not merged into the C++ standard yet. Such libraries include XSIMD, Google's Highway, VC. A SIMD library may not support all features provided by your target CPU (masking/predication is often a pain with a lot of C++ SIMD libraries), nor even a lot of CPU architectures. Its performance is dependent of many parameters like the target code, the target CPU architecture and the specific target SIMD instruction set. In general, you should compile the code for one specific SIMD instruction set. It means not supporting old CPU or being possibly sub-optimal on recent CPUs (unless you manually recompile the code for each possible SIMD instruction set and write a code to pick the best implementation which is tedious IMHO, especially for just one simple function).

OpenMP
Another alternative is to use OpenMP. SIMD directives are currently pretty limited and there is no guarantee that the code will be properly vectorized on the target compiler so you should check the assembly code to be sure. This solution is certainly the simplest though the generated code is generally sub-optimal. This is a good solution to easily get a faster portable code. In practice, OpenMP do not support a return statement in vectorized loops so the code must be adapted to operate on chunks. Moreover, lazy boolean operators tends not to be well vectorized by mainstream compilers. The 3 mainstream compilers seems to generate SIMD instructions in this case (though the MSVC warning is worrying) with the right compiler flags if the reduced variable is not a boolean (see on Godbolt). Here is the code:
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>

int check_adjacent_impl(uint8_t *arr, int size, int a, int b)
{
    constexpr int chunkSize = 256;
    const int chunkLimit = (size - 1) / chunkSize * chunkSize;

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i += chunkSize)
    {
        int res = 0;

        #pragma omp simd reduction(|:res)
        for (int j = i; j < std::min(i + chunkSize, size - 1); ++j)
            res |= ((arr[j] == a) & (arr[j + 1] == b)) | ((arr[j] == b) & (arr[j + 1] == a));

        if(res)
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

The generated code is clearly inefficient. However, using 8-bit variable (a, b and res) results in a much better assembly code (see on Godbolt). GCC still generate a sub-optimal code, but the one of Clang and MSVC are pretty good IMHO, especially the one of Clang:
.L5:
        vmovdqu ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [r13+0+rax]
        vmovdqu ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
        add     rax, 32
        vpcmpeqb        ymm0, ymm1, ymm4
        vpcmpeqb        ymm8, ymm2, ymm3
        vpcmpeqb        ymm1, ymm1, ymm3
        vpcmpeqb        ymm2, ymm4, ymm2
        vpand   ymm0, ymm0, ymm8
        vpand   ymm1, ymm1, ymm2
        vpor    ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vpand   ymm0, ymm0, ymm5
        vpor    ymm7, ymm7, ymm0
        cmp     rdx, rax
        jne     .L5


ISPC
Yet another solution is to simply use a SIMD-friendly language like ISPC or OpenCL (the later is better suited for accelerators like GPUs though). ISPC supports x86-like CPUs and ARM ones. It is mainly optimized for Intel CPUs and for 32-bit types. It is great to easily vectorize non-trivial code and get pretty-good performance (often sub-optimal though). Predication, swizzle, gathers and reduction operators are natively supported (and rather trivial to do). The code is portable and easier to maintain than with C SIMD intrinsics. Explicit vectorization guarantee that the code is vectorized as opposed to auto-vectorization or OpenMP directives. It also helps to optimize some codes better than most compilers (especially for skilled developers). The code tends to be more readable than C++ SIMD library though ISPC is a different language not supporting all C++ features so the integration with a C++ code can be sometime complicated. Note that ISPC is not really well suited for SIMD codes requiring a fixed vector size (eg. only 4 items) and AFAIK some very-specialized platform-specific intrinsics are not available (eg. _mm_mpsadbw_epu8). The big advantage of ISPC is that you can tell the compiler to generate codes for SSE2, SSE4.2, AVX2 and AVX-512 and choose the best implementation at runtime based on the target CPU with no development effort. Here is an (untested) example for your function (see on Godbolt):
static inline unmasked uniform bool checkBlock(uniform uint8 arr[], uniform int i, uniform uint8 a, uniform uint8 b)
{
    const int j = i + programIndex;
    const uint8 v1 = arr[j];
    const uint8 v2 = arr[j + 1];
    return any(((v1 == a) & (v2 == b)) | ((v1 == b) & (v2 == a)));
}

export uniform int check_adjacent_impl(uniform uint8 arr[], uniform int size, uniform uint8 a, uniform uint8 b)
{
    const uniform int vecSize = (size - 1) / programCount * programCount;

    // Main loop
    for(uniform int i = 0; i < vecSize; i += programCount)
        if(checkBlock(arr, i, a, b))
            return 1;
    
    // Last remaining items
    if(vecSize + programIndex < size - 1 && checkBlock(arr, vecSize, a, b))
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

On x86-64 CPUs, you can compile it with ispc code.ispc --target=sse2-i32x4,sse4.1-i8x16,avx2-i8x32,avx512skx-x64 (you may need --dllexport on Windows, or -pic on Linux regarding your needs) and then link the generated object files. It will run on all x86-64 CPUs and be pretty efficient. On ARM you just need to write --target=neon-i8x16 instead and that all (SVE is not currently supported). For example, here is the generated hot-loop AVX2 code:
.LBB1_3:
        vmovdqu ymm2, ymmword ptr [rdi + r9]
        vmovdqu ymm3, ymmword ptr [rdi + r9 + 1]
        vpcmpeqb        ymm4, ymm2, ymm0
        vpcmpeqb        ymm5, ymm3, ymm1
        vpand   ymm4, ymm5, ymm4
        vpcmpeqb        ymm2, ymm2, ymm1
        vpcmpeqb        ymm3, ymm3, ymm0
        vpand   ymm2, ymm3, ymm2
        vpor    ymm2, ymm4, ymm2
        vpmovmskb       r10d, ymm2
        test    r10d, r10d
        jne     .LBB1_4
        add     r9, 32
        cmp     r9, rsi
        jl      .LBB1_3

This seems very good IMHO (far better than your scalar code resulting in an assembly code full of conditional branches). It is similar to the OpenMP code generated with Clang but the ISPC code can stop earlier (because we do not operate on chunks in the ISPC code). This code should be dozens of times faster than your C++ scalar code on relatively-small arrays (ie. arrays fitting in your CPU L1/L2 caches). For large arrays, it should be memory-bound.

Note that your OpenMP version doesn't have an early-out.  It always scans the whole "haystack" string.  This is potentially good for branch-prediction, and means you can just accumulate in SIMD vectors without and SIMD to scalar-mask conversion necessary (the details and performance of which vary a lot between ISAs, e.g. very slow on some older ARMv7 CPUs, near free with AVX-512BW since mask registers are a native part of AVX-512, although manipulating them needs special insns, or a kmov to a GPR...)  But bad for huge haystacks with a hit near the start.  Oh, your last para mentions this.

@PeterCordes I am not sure to quite catch your comment. The OpenMP version has a kind of early-out but only at the end of the (relatively large) chunk. The size of the chunk can be reduce but this certainly decreases performance (chunks are pretty critical for the OpenMP implementation). Here there is just 2 characters to search so I think searching the two directly is faster unless one of the two character is very rare (not indicated in the OP so I prefer not to make assumptions about this). In this case, memchr might be better as you have pointed out.

@PeterCordes Isn't ARMv7 obsolete these days? (I expected the OP to mention this if this was a major target platform for this code anyway).

I think so yeah, even modern embedded stuff would I think normally use the AArch32 state of ARMv8 if they wanted thumb mode for more compact machine code, since even embedded CPUs are normally ARMv8.  But ARMv7 is not long gone, and made a good example of an ISA where it's inconvenient to branch on SIMD compare results.  The fact that some older CPUs also stalled on data transfer between SIMD and integer is just another fun fact to illustrate that there can be big differences between microarchitectures as well as ISAs.

Microcontrollers like Cortex-M4 are still used, though, and it optionally has some NEON SIMD instructions.  But it's in-order exec and not deeply pipelined so stalls in transfer from vector to GPR is presumably a thing.  But it's still the ARMv7 ISA.

What you are effectively trying to do is to find substrings of size 2 in a longer string. You could see if known substring matching algorithms (e.g. Boyer Moore) might provide some speedup for you. I see two potential caveats with my suggestion though:

Your substring is very short (just 2 characters), while most substring matching algorithms are designed for substrings that are a bit longer (hence they might not provide that much speedup compared to the naive implementation)
You want to match either of 2 alternatives at the same time (order doesn't matter to you), which requires some modifications to the textbook algorithms

Nevertheless, if you want to go down this path, someone has already compiled a website with
various explicit SIMD substring matching algorithms that you could use as a basis for an algorithm for your problem.
As an idea, if you follow the basic logic of the algorithm described on that website, you could maybe replace the initial "hashing" step they do with something that matches any combination of both a and b (i.e. aa, ab, ba, and bb), and then you just need the final check to narrow it down to ba and ab.
I haven't tried any of this, and I have no idea if this is faster or slower than your basic implementation, but maybe this is enough of a starting point to help out.
When you write the actual code, you might want to take a look at this preview of a SIMD library that will likely be part of future C++ standards, instead of just using plain intrinsics, especially since it makes writing portable code far easier.

I think you might want to do something like mask_a = movemask(cmpeq(v, set1('a')); and same for mask_b = ... set1('b')...;, and then maybe check (mask_a << 1) & mask_b and/or maybe the other shift direction.  If that's true then there's an a next to a b.  Or maybe some trickery to check for both possible orders with fewer ops.  The trick is at boundaries between vectors, unless you increment pointers by 15 instead of 16 or something and use unaligned loads.  Worth considering on modern x86 where unaligned loads are cheaper than lots of shuffling.

Wojciech Muła's avx2_strstr_anysize does compares on two different loads from the "haystack" string from different offsets, so maybe that's a good trick to borrow.  But otherwise it does more work than necessary when there aren't any characters between the start and end.
